# Merve builds Maven project on every launch on Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven, m2eclipse

I am using Eclipse, Maven 2, Merve (Tomcat launcher plugin for Eclipse), maven-eclipse plugin and m2eclipse.

My problem is that every time I run a launch with Merve, it invokes the Maven Project Builder which seems to make a full build. 
This takes a very long time for my project (about 2-3 minutes).

In the project properties -> Builders i have both the Java Builder and Maven Project Builder enabled.

Is there anything i can do to shorten the time? I'm guessing i should be able to configure it to build-compile only the sources that changed, not the entire project.

I am also open to other suggestions pluggins (like Jetty). I want to run and debug the maven project from eclipse and do it as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact cause to this problem but i solved it my installing another Eclipse with same plugins and changing the location of the workspace.
New eclipse, same workspace - same problem
New eclipse, new workspace - solved.